# Is there a way to write a group by query in LinqToSql grouping not on a scalar value?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have those maps in my repository.

```
public IQueryable<AwType> GetAwTypes()
{
    return from awt in _db.AwTypes
           select new AwType
           {
               Id = awt.Id,
               Header = awt.Header,
               Description = awt.Description
           };
}

public IQueryable<Aw> GetAws()
{
    return from aw in _db.Aws
           select new Aw
           {
               Id = aw.Id,
               Bw = (from bw in GetBws()
                          where bw.Id == aw.Bw
                             select bw
                         ).SingleOrDefault(),
               AwType = (from awt in GetAwTypes()
                            where awt.Id == awAwType
                            select awt
                        ).SingleOrDefault(),
               AwAttribute = aw.AwAttribute
           };
}
```

In service I want to get count of Bws grouped by AwType as `List<KeyValuePair<AwType, int>>`. 
When I call that linq query :

```
var awGroups = from aw in _repository.GetAws()
group aw by aw.AwType into newGroup
select newGroup;

List<KeyValuePair<AwType, int>> RetGroups = new List<KeyValuePair<AwType, int>>();
foreach (var group in awGroups)
{
    RetGroups.Add(new KeyValuePair<AwType, int>(group.Key, group.Count()));
}
return RetGroups;
```

I get an error that is saying I can't group by on an object I have to group by a scalar value like aw.AwType.Id.

Is there a way to get "AwType, int" pairs in one call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AwType is a reference type.  It would be a bad idea to group on that reference type...  Each AwType in that query is a unique reference, so n elements would yield n groups.

Try this:

```
var awGroups = from aw in _repository.GetAws()
group aw by aw.AwType.ID into newGroup  //changed to group on ID
select newGroup;

List<KeyValuePair<AwType, int>> RetGroups = new List<KeyValuePair<AwType, int>>();
foreach (var group in awGroups)
{
    //changed to get the first element of the group and examine its AwType
    RetGroups.Add(new KeyValuePair<AwType, int>(group.First().AwType, group.Count()));
}
return RetGroups;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've nearly gave up waiting an answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can group by an anonymous type, eg new { Foo, Bar }

Comment: do you mean group aw by new {Foo, Bar} ... 

I didn't understand what you mean...

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of linq, what you would be equivalent to trying to group by every column of a table. This can only be done by listing every single field in a table in the group statement, so in your case, you would need to do the following (I'm not very knowledgable about Linq)

```
var awGroups = from aw in _repository.GetAws()
group aw by aw.AwType.Id, aw.AwType.Header, aw.AwType.Description into newGroup
select newGroup;
```

or maybe you can just group by Id if that's the only column you need.

```
var awGroups = from aw in _repository.GetAws()
group aw by aw.AwType.Id into newGroup
select newGroup;
```